# What US states were added by year 2037?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In ST:TNG season 2 episode 12, "The Royale", the Enterprise crew discovers a lost US space mission apparently launched in the 2030's. They initially determine that time period based on finding several American flags which have 52 stars.

<sub>(Since there is one star on the US flag for each State, and different States were added to the US at different times, the number of states narrows down the possible date range).</sub>

**What were the two states had been added by the 2030s?**

(A net of two must have been added given that there were only 50 in the late 20th/early 21st centuries).

IIRC Earth history goes through some convulsions between that period and quite some time passes before civilization improves again (after, say, the events of "First Contact"). So I wonder if the political changes of that earlier period were related to the later problems on Earth.

[image: character holding a NASA board]

[image: USA flag]

Later the mission timeframe is confirmed by other sources.